# Maven build dependency issue

Tags: java, maven

i have issue while importing .jar of child project (model) to my other projects

- Parent pom

  - child1 jar
  - Child2 jar
  - Child3 war

Child1,2 and 3 each dependent on parent.

Upon building parent it build child 1,2 jar and child 3 war.

Child 1 is a model jar that will be use in other module.

Upon adding the jar to other modules it looking for parent.

How do I resolve such that I can use child1 as model jar to other module?

Here is my POM parent

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name> MyProject POM</name>
<modules>
    <module>/myprojectModel</module>
    <module>/myproject</module>
    <module>/myprojectService</module>
</modules>
```

Here is my Child 1 pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<groupId>com.emc.nrp</groupId>
<artifactId>nemsprerequisite-model</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name> Myproject Model</name>
```

So it will build 3 package

```
- Child1.jar

- Child2.jar

- Child3.war
```

When i import Child1.jar to another package it appear to have

Non-resolvable parent POM

This is the issue.

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-91) UT005023: Exception handling request to /business-central/maven2: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for com.myproject.myproject-model:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.myproject.myproject-model:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.myproject.myproject-parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ line 5, column 10

Comment: Try to change the `<module>` order in your parent pom. Maven will build top down. Btw, what error do you get?

Comment: What do you mean by "model jar"? What is the problem with the parent?

Comment: @FaltFe Maven does not build top down in general, it resolves dependencies between modules to find a correct order.

Comment: upon loading it mentioned Non-resolvable parent POM

Comment: First remove the leading slash from your list of modules...second it looks like you have wrong dependencies between the modules...best would be to setup an example project on github or alike ....

Comment: @isme Your project should also build and deploy the parent POM. How do you build it?

Comment: I build by clean install the parent module.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right click on src/java directory of all modules, and Click "Mark Directory as" and then click "Sources Root" as shown in below screenshot:
2. [image]select as sour

2.I think you should create on more module which loads all the child dependencies and have only Application.java in that module.

Follow [this link](https://medium.com/macoclock/how-create-multi-module-project-in-intellij-on-macos-50f07e52b7f9) for more details.

Comment: Hi, thank you this is what I followed however it still causing the error

Answer (score 0):

The relativePath element in your child pom is empty. Set that.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Do you mean child 1 in pom should have <relativePath>..</relativePath>

Comment: Yes, exactly. :-)